# Adding wildcard in jboss-web.xml

Tags: java, jboss

I have an application which is running on jboss 6 AS. In our application, we have an file to define virtual host entries as below.

```
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>java:/jaas/security-domain</security-domain>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <virtual-host>abc.com</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

Now i want to give an entry with wildcard, such as:

```
<virtual-host>*.abc.com</virtual-host>
```

All subdomains should be able to have access to app.

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make changes in jboss-web.xml for sub-domains. Comment or delete :-

```
<virtual-host>abc.com</virtual-host>
```

from jboss-web.xml file, instead you need to make changes in standalone.xml which is server configuring file JBoss server. Below i'm putting a sample piece of code, needs to written in standalone. Hope it helps.

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
    <alias name="localhost"/>
    <alias name="sub.domain.com"/>
</virtual-server>
```

And next change you need to make to web server(apache, if you've configured as loadbalancer above your application server i.e. Jboss) apache Conf file which is as follows :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    JkMount /yourapp/* jk
</VirtualHost>
```